# how to work around Ubuntu or gedit bug

Tags: ubuntu, gedit

Has anyone heard of this problem or does anyone have a workaround?  I am building an application in Coldfusion/javascript and am in Ubuntu 14.04. From time to time (rather often) a bunch of text gets dumped into random places in my code. It has even showed up on my terminal when it is open.  It could be something that may have been on the clipboard previously, but I'm not sure that is always the case.  It could well be from the "find" feature in gedit.  Or it could be something in Ubuntu.

I have changed both my keyboard and mouse, but the problem persists, so I don't think it is hardware.  This is slowing down my development, as random garbage keeps getting dumped into my code and I have to track it down and remove it.

Can anyone help?